# Invariant Violation error when displaying HTML-formatted text with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a React application that requires using an external API to get some text. The problem is that the text comes back as a string with HTML tags to show emphasis, for example:

```
{ "text": ["The quick <em class='hl'>brown</em> fox"] }
```

I had been using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` like so

```
{this.props.text.map(function(snippet) {
   return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: snippet }}></div>
})}
```

which worked most of the time, but I'm running into instances in which the text returned by the API is formatted in such a way that React throws the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invariant Violation: 
Danger: Expected markup to render 7 nodes, but rendered 4
```

It seems there is currently no way to [catch errors in the render function](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2461), so I can't just ignore problematic ones and continue.

Is a better way to handle things like text emphasis or highlighting with React, or perhaps there is a way to filter or trap strings that React may find problematic?

Comment: I should also note: when I receive that error, the maximum number of nodes I would expect is 5 (because there are 5 items in the array), so I'm not sure why it would expect 7...

Answer (score 4):

This problem really is cryptic! I noticed that occasionally the text snippets I was attempting to display contained `<` or `>`, which were seemingly throwing off React.

I did a regex replace on the tags I wished to keep (replaced them with `@@@` for the starting tag with the class and `***` for the closing tags), removed all instances of `<` or `>`, and then replaced the placeholders with their original markup.

Removing these extra symbols seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this issue occurs when the html passed in to dangerouslySetInnerHTML is undefined, or malformed, e.g. trying to substring() the html as if it were a string which causes it to be invalid.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content.substring(0, 360) }} />
```